# Combining two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I  have two tables in my database

`Winners` table:

```
Count   Country
--------------------
5       Hungary
2       Ireland
1       Italy
3       Netherlands
```

`RunnerUp` table:

```
Count     Country
----------------------
1         Italy
3         Netherlands
2         Spain
```

How do I combine these two tables to look like this:

```
Country     Winners    RunnerUp
--------------------------------
Hungary       5          0
Ireland       2          0
Italy         1          1
Netherlands   3          3
Spain         0          2
```

Comment: You can join the tables an change the name of the column count using Count as Winners and count as RunnerUp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Union

```
Select Country , Sum(Winners) as Winners, Sum(RunnerUp)  as RunnerUp 
FROM
(
Select Count as Winners , 0 as RunnerUp, Country from Winners 
Union ALL
Select 0  as Winners , Count as RunnerUp, Country from RunnerUp
) a
Group By Country
```

Answer (score 0):

The construct you're looking for is a `full outer join`:

```
SELECT          COALESCE([winners].[country], [runnerup].[country]) AS country,
                COALESCE([winners].[count], 0) AS winners, 
                COALESCE([runnerup].[count], 0) AS runnerup
FROM            [winners]
FULL OUTER JOIN [runnerup] ON [winners].[country] = [runnerup].[country]
```

Comment: This wont work for teams that dont have any wins and runners up that dont have any wins.

Answer (score 0):

I would use case statements in your select with a correlated sub query using EXISTS to determine what value to show for a country (0 if it doesn't exist, the value in the table if it does).

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT 
    countries.Country,
    CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Winners.Country 
                   FROM Winners 
                   WHERE countries.Country = Winners.Country) 
          THEN (SELECT SUM(Count) 
                FROM Winners 
                WHERE countries.Country = Winners.Country) 
       ELSE 0 
    END AS Winners,
    CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS(SELECT RunnerUp.Country 
                   FROM RunnerUp 
                   WHERE countries.Country = RunnerUp.Country) 
          THEN (SELECT SUM(Count) 
                FROM RunnerUp 
                WHERE countries.Country = RunnerUp.Country) 
       ELSE 0 
    END AS RunnerUp
FROM 
    (SELECT Country FROM Winners
     UNION
     SELECT Country FROM RunnerUp) as countries
```

I union the country names so the results have all countries whether or not they appear in both tables. The `SELECT` statement in the `THEN` part of the case statements can only return a single value, so I used the sum() aggregate. This way, if for some reason a country shows up in the same table more than once, I'll get the total for both times.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and — much more importantly — standards-compliant rather than relying upon nonsense functions like `COALESCE()` that are not needed in an already functionally complete RDBMS:

```
CREATE TABLE RESULTS( COUNTRY, WINNERS, RUNNER_UP ) PRIMARY KEY( COUNTRY );

INSERT INTO RESULTS  
SELECT W.COUNTRY, W.COUNT AS WINNERS  
FROM WINNERS W  
INNER JOIN ON W.COUNTRY = R.COUNTRY  
SELECT R.COUNTRY, R.COUNT AS RUNNER_UP  
FROM RUNNERS_UP R;
```

Comment: In case no one has pointed out this resource to you, here is some info to better format your answers: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)